# Safari 6.1 weird bug when absolutely positionning a div inside a fixed div

Tags: javascript, safari

Yesterday I was working on a menu with several items. Inside this fixed nav bar I had to add an absolute  div which will be displayed on the hover of one of the menu item.

It works perfectly on every browsers except **Safari 6.1.1** (latest version so far). Indeed, as soon as the absolutely positioned div appeared all the textfields inside the menu glitched.

Note that if the absolute div doesn't overflow its parent the bug won't happen.

I made a minimal Jsfiddle to highlight the bug:

http://jsfiddle.net/tz9s3/5/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="fixed-block">
    Random text 1
    Random text 2
    <div class="absolute-block">
        Random text 3
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.fixed-block {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background:#000000;
    position:fixed;
    height: 100px;
    width: 80px;
}
.fixed-block .absolute-block{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    font-size:18px;
}
.fixed-block:hover > .absolute-block {
    display: block;
}
```

Any suggestions or fix for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally answered my own question.

You can fix this bug using the webkit property on the fixed parent:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
```

I updated my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tz9s3/6/